# 404 not found on laravel post request

Tags: laravel

I'm making a post request in my form. The `csrf token` and the method are there.

```
<div class="flex">
    <form action="{{ route('profile.store.follower', $user) }}" method="post">      
        @csrf 
        <input value="follow" type="hidden" name="follow" value="{{$user->id}}" >
        <button type="submit" class="bg-green-700">Follow</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**The route**:

```
Route::get('/usersprofile/{user:name}/index', [ProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('profile.index');
Route::post('/usersprofile/{user:name}/index', [ProfileController::class, 'store'])->name('profile.store.follower');
```

**The controller**:

```php
    public function store(User $user, Request $request) {
        dd($user);
        $user = user::findOrFail($request->follow);
        Auth::user()->following->attach($user->id);
 
        return back();
    }
```

The following function in the user model:

```
public function following() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'user_id', 'following_id');
}
```

For some reason, it's not going through. I've tried `php artisan route:cache` and `config:cache` but the error persists. I've checked the route list and the route exists.

Comment: I don't think you need `user:name` just `user` should be enough

Comment: I still get the same error though

Comment: can you dd($user) and show us what value it is

Comment: It's not going through. dd($user) is what is currently in the controller, but I still get the 404 error

Comment: @Shanediesel can you show controller code where you return blade

Comment: 1. Does the route appear in `route:list` 2. What's the signature of your `store` method in your controller?

Comment: I updated with the controller. @Peppermintology the route is in the list. It's store

Comment: @JohnLobo I had the dd in the wrong spot, now it returns the user that I'm trying to follow

Comment: You have two `value` attributes in your hidden input. And `user::findOrFail...` should most likely be  `User::findOrFail...`. What's that hidden input even for if the user is already available via url?

Comment: Personally I'd not use the `store()` method but a dedicated method for following users (`follow()` or something). Remove your hidden input and the line `$user = user::findOrFail($request->follow);` since the user you want to follow already exists in `$user`. Then use `Auth::user()->following->attach($user);`

Comment: @brombeer Thanks I have no idea how I put two values in there, it works now. It's difficult to find good tutorials about following, so I tried setting it up myself. Put your response as an answer so I can make it the best one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hidden input has two `value` attributes, that's probably why it doesn't find a user and fails.

Remove the hidden input and the line `$user = user::findOrFail($request->follow);` - the user you want to follow already exists in `$user` via your route. Then use `Auth::user()->following->attach($user);` to follow.

```
<div class="flex">
  <form action="{{ route('profile.store.follower', $user) }}" method="post">      
    @csrf 
    <button type="submit" class="bg-green-700">Follow</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
public function store(User $user, Request $request)
{
    Auth::user()->following->attach($user);
    return back();
}
```